# Python Script for Linux IP Enumeration - Not working as expected

Tags: python, linux, bash, ip

I've written a simple script that allows me to use a while loop to iterate a ping command over an ip range.

I'm unsure as to why I keep getting this message back afterwards:

[image: Example of feedback from Terminal]

The code is as follows:

```py
import os

ipnum = 0

iprange = '10.11.1.%s' % (ipnum)
while ipnum < 255:
    os.system("ping " + iprange)
    ipnum + 1**
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just to note I did import os - the question omitted that part out.

Comment: Did you mean `ipnum += 1`?

Comment: Hi thanks Zain I changed the code to the += operator - still getting the error message.

Comment: You seem to be pinging 10.11.1.0 continuously, because the string doesn't magically update once `ipnum` does.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is something like:

```
for ipnum in range(0, 255):
    os.system("ping 10.11.1.%s" % ipnum)
```

What your code currently does is ping `10.11.1.0` 255 times, because the string doesn't update just because `ipnum` does. You format it once at the beginning and then don't modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You use some tools like nmap, angryip. 
If you want a python, we can rewrite that

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
target = 200
up = 0
down = 0
while (target < 255):
    ip = "10.11.1." +str(target)
    output = subprocess.Popen(["ping","-c","1",ip],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    if ('Unreachable' in output):
            print 'Host ' + ip + " is offline or unavailable"
            down+= 1
    else:
            print "Host " + ip + " is online"
            up+= 1

    target = target+1


print "A total of " + str(up+down) + " hosts were scanned."
print str(up) + " hosts were alive, and " + str(down) + " hosts were unreachable. "
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is enumerate a list of active IPs in given a range, why not use something that already exists for that purpose?

Checkout nmap:

```
sudo nmap -sn -n 10.11.1.0- -oG - | grep -i Host | cut -d" " -f2
```

The above command:

- nmap : scan the netwrok
- -sn + -sP : skip port scanning

  - faster host discovery
- -n : skip reverse dns resolution

  - faster host discovery
- 10.11.1.- : enumerate over 10.11.1.0

  - the dash specifies to enumerate
- -oG - : convert the output for data processing
- grep -i Host : filter the output to only show enumerated values

  - removes the header and footer of the nmap output
- cut -d" " -f2 : split the output into columns separated by spaces, then filter to only show the second column.

  - shows just the ip addresses

Sample output

```
sudo nmap -sn -n 10.11.1.0.- -oG - | grep Host | cut -d" " -f2                                                            
# 10.11.1.0.1
# 10.11.1.0.100
# 10.11.1.0.101
# 10.11.1.0.103
# 10.11.1.0.106
# 10.11.1.0.169
# 10.11.1.0.108
```

Nmap supports scanning the current hosts' network range, as well any other network range.

---

If you need to execute this directly from python, use the `subprocess` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

---

More information about nmap:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap

Comment: Because it's an exercise I need to get my head around in Python. I'm aware of the various tools and Bash but I need to write this in Python. Thanks though

Comment: Its actually very common for scripts in other languages to call bash scripts or external tools like nmap. Since this was tagged with linux and bash, I assumed my solution could be appropriate.